# Edit Success message and link in Opencart / Mijoshop

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Im trying to remove the link to a product in the success bar when adding a product to the cart from a category page but for the life of me I cant find where to edit the link!

I've searched the entire site and found the message and link in opencart > catalog > language > english > checkout > cart.php but editing this doesnt work and it cant be found anywhere else except wishlish and compare!

Any ideas on getting to this would be great. Im only trying to remove the link to the product page in the message, nothing else.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, all you need to do is to change this translation

```
$_['text_success']           = 'Success: You have added <a href="%s">%s</a> to your <a href="%s">shopping cart</a>!';
```

to this

```
$_['text_success']           = 'Success: You have added %2$s to your <a href="%3$s">shopping cart</a>!';
```

That should do the work. Take a look at [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf).